# How much difference does the order of properties in a css file effect it's compression

Tags: css, performance, compression, gzip

In a css file, how much difference is there between a file where the properties are in the same order for all selectors and one where they are randomly ordered, when considering the compressed output provided a process such as GZip.

Has anyone investigated this with some real examples and numbers they could share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As order of bits always make a difference with compression, it will make a difference. But not as you could say one is better than the other. It's more like random (for us developers) which one will result in some bits more or less. But I think you will spent more time on finding the optimal solution than it would change something.

But remember, that some old IE had a functional difference considering the order of elements. As I remember, there was something that position had to be set before you want to set top, left, right, bottom and `z-index` (so attributes that only work when you have position).

I would just mind readability. This saves the most time (and by that money) during development :)